# PHP Soap Authentication header 599

Tags: php, soap

I am new on php Soap web service. I am trying to create client / server mechanism which will exchange some basic data. This i already did. But, i need help how to send header authentication details from client and how to parse it on server (example, username, password, and API Key) ?

Can you please give me basic example, i really need it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you

The SOAP client statement as look like

```
$client = new SoapClient("name.wsdl",array(
"trace"      => 1,
"exceptions" => 0,
"login" => 'xxx',
"password" => 'xxx'));
```

at server

I used this PHP statement for Authenticate PHP Auth header

```
    if(($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']!= $pass
 || $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] != $login)
 || !$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])
    {
        header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Test auth"');
        header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
        // OR ANY THING
}
```

**UPDATE**

You can use it like this

```
$client = new SoapClient(WSDL,array());

$auth = array(
        'UserName'=>'USERNAME',
        'Password'=>'PASSWORD',
        'SystemId'=> array('_'=>'DATA','Param'=>'PARAM'),
        );
  $header = new SoapHeader('NAMESPACE','Auth',$auth,false);
  $client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer . I am not sure that this is authentication using soap header. Am i right ?